# Removal of blocking artifacts in images due to compression

Tags: image-processing

Having compressed an image,how can the compression noise or blocking artifacts be suppressed to improve the quality of the image before further processing. Thanks

Comment: is the "quality" with respect to the "further process" or the "final viewer" ?

Comment: Thanks. The quality is in respect to further process. My interest is not image viewing but suppressing the effect of noise for better accuracy in my final processing.

Comment: ok. Most de-blocking algorithms in the block-based transform coding literature are optimized wrt human viewers. You shall somewhat adjust them to fit into the "further" processes sensitivity characteristics.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried some but with no improvement and I think adjustment is an option. I will appreciate any further suggestion that can work. I am trying to reduce the compression noise on the PRNU characteristics of an image after the image has undergone compression

Comment: Which further processing are you aiming at? Depending on its properties, you may want to remove artifacts differently, because artifacts are often composite (blocking is not only a shift in the mean luminance of a block)

Comment: Thanks, I uses the Sensor pattern noise of a camera to distinguish an image coming from it or not. if the image is compressed before the extraction, this pattern is suppressed by the compression noise. So, I need a pre-processing algorithm that will reduce the artifacts due to compression so that it will not affect the overall classification accuracy. I am trying to explore your suggestion, though further suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about JPEG-like blocking artifacts, an interesting appproach consists in the re-applications of the same JPEG algorithm on shifted versions of the image, see [Enhancement of JPEG-Compressed Images by
Re-application of JPEG](http://www.utdallas.edu/~aria/papers/vlsisp99.pdf), by Aria Nosratinia, 1999. It has a [software implementation](http://www.utdallas.edu/~aria/mcl/post/). It implement a sort of shift-invariant processing. He did the same with the JPEG-2000 coder, in [Post-Processing of JPEG-2000 Images to Remove Compression Artifacts](http://%20www.utdallas.edu/~aria/papers/spl03.pdf). You can find [an overview of these artifacts here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~jakulin/jpeg/artifacts.htm).

Improved methods include sparsifying priors like total variation, see for instance [Adapted Total Variation for Artifact Free Decompression of JPEG Images](http://doi.org/10.1007/s10851-005-6467-9). Recent references include [Reducing Artifacts in JPEG Decompression Via a Learned Dictionary](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2013.2290508) and [Understanding, Optimising, and Extending Data Compression with Anisotropic Diffusion](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11263-014-0702-z).

Comment: @I.O Animasahun If you give more specific details about your processing, you might get more involved techniques, but you can try  the most basic ones first.

Comment: Thanks, I uses the Sensor pattern noise of a camera to distinguish an image coming from it or not. if the image is compressed before the extraction, this pattern is suppressed by the compression noise. So, I need a pre-processing algorithm that will reduce the artifacts due to compression so that it will not affect the overall classification accuracy. I am trying to explore your suggestion, though further suggestion is appreciated